# Quaternion values from Arduino 9-axis motion shield seem very wrong

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

I am currently usinga BNO055 sensor fitted on the Arduino Nine-axis motion shield to measure ocean wave heights and periods. To do this, I'd like to use the quaternions provided, however I have a slight issue. A quaternion should be <cos(theta/2), X*sin(theta/2), Y*sin(theta/2), Z*sin(theta/2)>, with X, Y and Z the coordinates of a unit vector and theta the angle of rotation around that vector. Therefore, I expect all three to be inferior to one.

However, when I run a simple code to see the raw data, the W given by my sensor when on the table is 16 375, and X, Y and Z values are in the high hundreds range...

This gives me a wave height of hundreds of thousands of kilometers :slightly_smiling_face:

Does anyone know why this happens? Do I need to divide the quaternion by it's norm to get the correct result? Or maybe I am misunderstanding the use of a quaternion?

Oh, and I have calibrated the sensor beforehand

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this sensor, so I am just guessing.

The sensor is likely giving you [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) numbers. Judging from
the real part, there are most likely 14 bits right of the implicit
radix point. If that is the case, the actual quaternion can be computed
as:

```c
float w = raw_w / 16384.0;
float x = raw_x / 16384.0;
float y = raw_y / 16384.0;
float z = raw_z / 16384.0;
```

You can check whether this is reasonable by computing the norm, which
should be very close to one.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't understand the explanation but your solution worked!